# Using logman to collect data

Tags: windows, logging

I try to use logman instead of DDK tracelog for colecting *.etl data produced by my application that uses WPP but was not able to see any data (in *.etl) after reading the etl file and decoding *.fmt information by using traceview.

What am I doing wrong? I generate *etl like this

logman start "Session" -o "Trace.etl" -p "{28EE579B-CF67-43b6-9D19-8930E7AAA131}" -ets
logman stop "Session"  -ets

When opening with traceview the generated Trace.etl it shows not errors only that there is no collected data there.

EDIT: I specify that I registered my generated *.mof file using mofcompiler on the system and that by using traceview directly I can see data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the fact that I didn't specify any flags and because of that (WPP messages being with flags set I was not seeing any data:

logman start "Session" -o "Trace.etl" -p "{28EE579B-CF67-43b6-9D19-8930E7AAA131}" **0xFFFF** -ets logman stop "Session" -ets

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same issue and found this useful documentation on MSDN:

[CLR ETW Keywords and Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff357720(v=vs.110).aspx)

The levels have the following meanings:

- 0x5 - Verbose
- 0x4 - Informational
- 0x3 - Warning
- 0x2 - Error
- 0x1 - Critical
- 0x0 - LogAlways